# Quantum to String: making the transition

Tags: quantum-mechanics, string-theory

We have a Hamiltonian containing a quantum simple harmonic oscillator coupled to a meter and a force. There is a term in the Hamiltonian that involves the oscillator position and the force, a term that involves the oscillator position and the meter momentum, a term containing the particle position and a final one containing the particle momentum.

We want to convert this to the string theory picture: what happens when we replace the quantum point particle and the meter with strings?

Comment: I don't understand a question what you mean that you have a "meter"?

Comment: The meter is another quantum device (characterized by its position and momentum) that is coupled to the particle.